# Is there anyway to add the custom HTML/Script in the head tag on static pages via any application?

Tags: html, web, cloudflare

I want to add my custom script tag / html code in the head tag to all the static pages. I can manually add my script to the static pages, but i have more than 10,000+ static web pages, so if I were to start editing my code it will be so much time consuming. I want to know is there application out there which can help me to achieve this result. I tried cloudflare which is best for custom apps but I didn't find any app which will allow me to add custom script to my head tag. Anyway to add script automatically?

Is there any application out there or app that will be automatically add my script to the head tags on my live website pages? **I prefer adding on live website.**

Thanks

Comment: What kind of access do you have? Would you be able to write a custom middleware? Or run a script in the file directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- **Find in Files** function of [Notepad++](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-use-the-find-in-files-feature-in-notepad.html)
- **Find and Replace** function of [Adobe Dreamweaver](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/find-replace-text.html)

Both of this functions has a find in documents function, where in you could search and replace from multiple folders at once. But take note that you must provide the unique part to replace, for example:

FIND:

```
</head>
```

REPLACE:

```
<!-- YOUR SCRIPT HERE -->
</head>
```

And lastly don't forget to backup first, just a friendly reminder :D

Comment: Yup I got it, thanks for the answer. It will work but not for newly added pages as I have to again place my script on those pages. Is there any other application out there or app that will be automatically add my script to the head tags on my live website pages? I prefer adding on live website. For example: Cloudflare apps that work on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs have a find/replace feature that works on a file basis.  You could load your entire repository in Visual Studio Code, for example, and it would do it.  It also has a filename filter to help.  It would take a few minutes, but it would get the job done.

Also, I'm really curious how you ended up with 10,000+ static files without something generating them that you could modify.

Comment: I share your curiosity. 3+ of anything and I'm looking for a way to automate.